# What is wrong with push()?

Tags: javascript

What is wrong with push() in the next code?

```
var userInput = {};
var input = '' + $(this).text();
console.log('input=' + input); //success
userInput.push(input); //Uncaught TypeError: userInput.push is not a function
```

Comment: userInput is an object, push is an Array method

Comment: Sidenote: its possible to use Array methods on an object, ie: `Array.prototype.push.call(userInput, 'foo')`. It's very unlikely you'll need this though. Use an array instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.push` is an array method. `{}` is an object, and you can't `push` onto objects.

You could either use `[]` to make `userInput` an array, or you could keep it an object and add things like this:

```
var userInput = {};
userInput["myInput"] = input;
// or...
userInput.myInput = input;
```

Also:

```
var input = '' + $(this).text();
```

The `'' +` is unnecessary. It's saying to "add an empty string to this other string", which doesn't do anything. It's like how if you add `0` to `5`, you still have `5`.

This is fine:

```
var input = $(this).text();
```

Answer (score 4):

You are declaring an object and trying to push, it should be an array. Try declaring like  this,

```
var userInput = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.you can't push an object to an array.

```
var userInput = [];
var input = '' + $(this).text();
console.log('input=' + input); //success
userInput.push(input);
```